# How to filter elements by a List item in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a user that belongs to a community with a specific role, The classes of User, Community, CommunityRole and CommunityRoleType are described bellow:

```
public class User{
    public int UserId { get; set;}  
    public List<CommunityRole> CommunityRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Community{
    public int CommunityId { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public enum CommunityRoleType{
    Type1,
    Type2
}
public class CommunityRole { 
    public Community Community { get; set; }
    public CommunityRoleType RoleType {get; set; }
}
```

How do I get, from a list of users, the subset of users that belong to a specific community and are assigned a specific role??

Comment: What have you tried so far to accomplish this, and what specific problems are you having with your attempted solutions?

Comment: Can we see your `UserCommunityRole` class?

Comment: "Assumming there's a class Community"...Why don't you just put the code to the Community class as well?

Comment: @BenRobinson I think that UserCommunityRole is the same as CommunityRole, and he just has a typo there

Comment: it is a typo. I'll correct it,

Comment: so bottom line.. what is the question 
1) all the users in a community who have a CommunityRoleType Type1 using linq method sintax?
or
2) I'm stuck trying to filter out the roles that do not belong to the community specified by communityId

Comment: I want the users in a specific Community that have a specific CommunityRoleType

Comment: I included my specific approach in response to @Servy comment. However, I'm actually opened to anything that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

```
var usersType1 = users.Where(usr => usr.CommunityRoles.Any(role => 
                              role.RoleType == CommunityRoleType.Type1
                                   && role.Community.CommunityId == communityID)).ToList();
```

Comment: `CommunityRoles` is a `List<UserCommunityRole>` not a `List<CommunityRole>`.

Comment: a vote down without a constructive comment is really productive :)

Comment: Yes, I did. This will work nicely to get a specific CommunityRoleType but not in a specific Community.

Comment: Could you be so kind to both stucture and bold your question?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to rewrite it instead of adding an extra edit, this time.

Comment: I rewrote the question in regards of clarity. Hope it's clear enough now.

Answer (score 0):

> all the users in a community who have a CommunityRoleType Type1

If only you had said "all users in *this* community" (i.e. the Community you mention just before):

```
var users = _context.Users
            .Where(u => u.CommunityRoles
                         .Any(cr => cr.RoleType == CommunityRoleType.Type1
                                 && cr.Community.CommunityId == someCommunityId ));
```